# Remove previous declaration with module augmentation

Tags: typescript

I want to overload the [`navigate`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/edc4ace20009b991f67103b19c2d769744f48a05/typescript/react-navigation.d.ts#L728-L732) function of `react-navigation` to have better type checking.

```
navigate(
  routeNameOrOptions: string,
  params?: NavigationParams,
  action?: NavigationAction,
): boolean
```

I defined my overload like this:

```
type Routes = 'Dashboard' | 'Profile'

declare module 'react-navigation' {
  export interface NavigationScreenProp<S, P = NavigationParams> {
    navigate(
      routeNameOrOptions: Routes,
      params?: NavigationParams,
      action?: NavigationAction,
    ): boolean
  }
}
```

It works but the `string` type is still available so `navigate('Invalid')` is not a type error.

How can I "remove" the previous declaration to only have mine?

Answer (score 0):

You still get the other overloads, because TypeScript does [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) of all your ambient module declarations. I really don't know of any way to subtract specific module type members (here the function overload) from another defined module augmentation.

Honestly, the easiest option would be to wrap the external type `NavigationScreenProp` as a custom type specific in your router-layer or so.

```
type Routes = 'Dashboard' | 'Profile'

type Router = {
  navigate(
      routeNameOrOptions: Routes,
      params?: NavigationParams,
      action?: NavigationAction,
  ): boolean
}
```

`type Routes = 'Dashboard' | 'Profile'` is a domain specific restriction just for your app. Module augmentations/ambient module declarations are more suited to provide/fix missing/wrong or too broad types of a package (and then it would be better to concat the owner for a fix).

*Update*:

Deleted my proposal with tsconfig `paths`, as it did not work out well for me in a sample. Also I think, above solution is the best to maintain and easiest for your use case. Hope, it helps.